# Query databases with node.js

Tags: node.js

I have been trying to pull info from a database and insert into another database. They are two different connections. I was trying to write a cross query to two different sources in the same query, but it doesn't work.
I think the solution is to pull the data and save it in variable and in another query insert the resulting data.

Does anyone know how to use merge with dual to be able to insert?

I have been trying to pull info from a database and insert into another database (using oracle sql). They are two different connections. I was trying to write a cross query to two different sources in the same query, but it doesn't work.
I think the solution is to pull the data and save it in variable and in another query insert the resulting data.

Does anyone know how to use merge with dual to be able to insert?

Here is the code I'm using

```
console.log("starting test.js here");
import dbconfig from "../lib/database/dbconfig";
import { db_Query } from "../query";

export const testRoute = {
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/api/test',
    handler: async (req, h) =>  {
      
        var binds = {};
        
       
        const sql1= select value1, value2, value3 from table1 WHERE value1="a" AND value2 ="B";
        const sql2= `MERGE INTO table2 tgt using (select '" + value1 + "' value1, '"+ value2 +"' value2, '"+ value3 +"' value3,'" + " FROM DUAL)
        src on (src.value1=tgt.value1)" + " when matched then UPDATE SET "+ "tgt.value2=src.value2 + when not matched then INSERT ( " + value1, value2, value3") 
        VALUES ('" + value1 +"','"+ value2 +"','"+ value3 +"' "+");
        console.log("sql1: " + sql1);
        console.log("calling db_Query");
        const { results } = await db_Query (sql1,sql2,binds);

        console.log(results.rows);

        //return rows only, no metahead
        return results.rows;
                
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the code I'm using

Comment: This **urgently** needs placeholder values. Do not use string concatenation to compose SQL queries. Most libraries make this really easy, as in `VALUES (?, ?, ?...)` and then you just supply an array of values. It looks like you have `binds` here already, you're just not using it.

Comment: I don't think that's the code you're using.

Comment: I was able to insert, I tested the query in oracle sql developer but when I run the code in node.js. I'm getting the following error

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error

Comment: Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error